# Prove whether a non-numeric predicate statement is true or false while giving reasons?

Tags: predicate-logic

I am studying discrete math at university. However, the materials don't seem to explain non-numeric predicate statements in much detail. I am asked to prove that a predicate statement is false using nested quantifiers and give reasons. The statement is this:

> For all the simple things you have done to me, there exists one thing that makes me happy.

---

My predicate statement is something like this but I'm confused about how to prove it is false.

```
Let
UD= All things
S(x)= x is a simple thing you have done to me
H(x)= x is a thing that makes me happy

∀x ( S(x) → ∃!y H(y) )
```

If someone could please explain how you are supposed to go about this, or perhaps provide a link, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > For all the simple things you have done to me, there exists one thing that makes me happy.

(We presume that the things that make them happy is a subset of the aforementioned simple things.)

1. Your translation $$∀x ( S(x) → ∃!y H(y) )$$ is incorrect because “there exists one thing” doesn't mean “there exists *exactly* one thing”.
2. The given statement is literally translated as $$∀x∃x ( S(x) →  H(x) ),$$ which is logically equivalent to $$∀x ( S(x) →  H(x) ),$$ which can be translated back as “Every simple thing that you have done to me makes me happy.”

The speaker probably means “***Among*** the simple things you have done to me, there exists one thing that makes me happy” instead.

In this case, the translation is $$∃x S(x) → ∃x ( H(x) ∧ S(x) ),$$  which is logically equivalent to $$∀x ∃y (S(x) → ( H(y) ∧ S(y) )$$ and to $$∃y ∀x (S(x) → ( H(y) ∧ S(y) ).$$